# Issues connecting to aws ec2 instance behind eip

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, ip-address

I have an ec2 instance on which I'm running a dev server via `parcel index.html --host 0.0.0.0` that ultimately listens on `0.0.0.0:1234`.  Before creating and associating an eip to my instance, I wanted to use the public ip address assoc'd with it and modified my iptables via

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 1234
```

This allowed me to visit my server via the browser using the public ip address assoc'd with my ec2 instance and receive the response I expect.

However, I've now created and assoc'd an eip with my instance (because it's a dev server and I start and stop the instance regularly, I want a constant ip address) and although I can continue to ssh into my instance via the eip address, I can't visit the server by using the eip address in my browser.

Since I'm able to ssh to the instance via the eip I wonder if there is some configuration local to the instance that I need to modify to make requests to my server.

Here are the inbound rules for the security group assoc'd with my instance.
[image: Security group inbound rules]

Comment: I suspect this is something to do with iptables or your application, rather than AWS or elastic IPs. Once running EC2 is basically a standard Linux server.

Comment: That security group seems right. Are you sure your custom iptables rule is still present and effective?

Comment: @Michael Hampton It looks like that was the issue!  Do those iptables rules get reset each time I stop and start the instance?  Is there a way to make them constant?

Comment: Maybe like this, but there are different methods suggested that can be found via Google https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-make-iptables-rules-persistent-after-reboot-on-linux